# How to parse nested comma-separated lists of parenthesized expressions

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I know how to use the Python regex module to parse nested parentheses. This regular expression

```
\(([^()]*+(?:(?R)[^()]*)*+)\)
```

correctly finds the outermost parentheses in

```
some (text)(text here(possible text)text(possible text(more text)))end text
```

(example [here](https://regex101.com/r/oC2qW2/1))

I also know how to find items in a comma-separated list:

```
[^,]+(?=,?)
```

matches correctly the elements of the list

```
dgad asg , adgda adg, a, g, asdgdg,dg sfg
```

(see [here](https://regex101.com/r/oC2qW2/22))

But I need a combination of these two. I need to parse the elements of a comma separated list, where the elements themselves may contain parantheses (with comma-separated lists in them). In this list

```
dg(dsfsd, (d,d,g)(g,as(d,f) fdg) sdfs, sf)ad asg , adgda (a) adg, a, g, asdgdg,dg sfg(f,g, (dff, d)df, g) kd
```

I need to identify the elements as:

```
first: dg(dsfsd, (d,d,g)(g,as(d,f) fdg) sdfs, sf)ad asg
second: adgda (a) adg
third: a
fourth: g
fifth: asdgdg
sixth: dg sfg(f,g, (dff, d)df, g) kd
```

I don't know how to combine the two regular expressions. Could someone help me, please? Thx.

Comment: Can there be unpaired `(` and `)` in the entries? `asd(gh, e(a(b))`?

Comment: Unpaired parens should result in an error. (No match.) Actually, I would like to get all the valid elements up to the defective one. I think...

Comment: (?R) is valid in the "regex" module (not in the default module "re").

Comment: Try [`^([^,()]*(\((?:[^()]*+(?:(?2)[^()]*)*+)\))*[^,()]*(?:,|$))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/TCmefD/1)

Comment: Try [`(?>(\((?>[^()]*(?1)?)*\))|[^,])+`](https://regex101.com/r/SXMjN7/1). It will match values with `(`, but in case you want to filter them out, you can always run a simple list comprehension, e.g. `[x for x in result if '(' in x]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Wow! It works! Thank you very much! Please write it as a proper answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?>(\((?>[^()]*(?1)?)*\))|[^,])+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXMjN7/2)

**Details**

- `(?>(\((?>[^()]*(?1)?)*\))|[^,])+` - 1 or more occurrences of (to avoid empty string matches):

  - `(\((?>[^()]*(?1)?)*\))` - Capturing group 1 (defined to be able to use a subroutine) matching:

    - `\(` - a `(`
    - `(?>[^()]*(?1)?)*` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` followed with an optional whole Group 1 pattern (recursed here)
    - `\)` - a `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]` - any char but `,`

Python demo:

```
import regex as re

rx = r"(?>(\((?>[^()]*(?1)?)*\))|[^,])+"
s = "dg(dsfsd, (d,d,g)(g,as(d,f) fdg) sdfs, sf)ad asg , adgda (a) adg, a, g, asdgdg,dg sfg(f,g, (dff, d)df, g) kd"
matches = re.finditer(rx, s)
for m in matches:
    print(m.group().strip())
```

Output:

```
dg(dsfsd, (d,d,g)(g,as(d,f) fdg) sdfs, sf)ad asg
adgda (a) adg
a
g
asdgdg
dg sfg(f,g, (dff, d)df, g) kd
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. With explanations, plus Python usage example... More than I hoped. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I enhanced it a little. Now I can capture errors (unbalanced parens): `r'(?> ( \( (?> [^()]*(?1)?)* \) ) | [^,()]+ | (?P<error>[()]+) )+'` (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/SXMjN7/3))